# how bind my front with my back end (form contact)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sendmail, nodemailer

I am learning JS using react. I have created a simple form with react and nodemailer as a test.

If I just use my file email.js that corresponds to my backEnd file I can send email.

With my contact.jsx file I can print form and get the input values.

But I can't bind these files.

I wish create simple contact form. Collect value of input in my email.js and after send email when user submit.

Here is my email.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: '******@gmail.com',
        pass: '*******'
    }
});

var mailOptions = {
    from: '*****@gmail.com',
    to: '*****@gmail.com',
    subject: 'CRG WEB SITE',
    text: '{input value (Email, message...}'//Collect value of input
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

And here is contact.jsx with react.

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/Contact.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import {  ControlLabel , FormControl, FormGroup,  Button, Grid, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'



export class Contact extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);

        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        return (

            <div className="Contact">
                <Grid>
                <Row className="show-grid">
                    <Col xs={10} xsOffset={1}>
                        <div className="BlockPrincipal">
                            <h2> Contact</h2>

                            <form className="contactForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 

                                <FormGroup>
                                    <ControlLabel>Last name</ControlLabel>
                                    <FormControl className="formField" id="Lname"  type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Jean-Louis" />
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup>
                                <ControlLabel>Email</ControlLabel>
                                <FormControl className="formField" id="Fmail"   type="email" placeholder="jean-louis@mail.com" />
                                </FormGroup>

                                <FormGroup>
                                <ControlLabel>Subject</ControlLabel>
                                <FormControl className="formField" componentClass="textarea" placeholder="Write you're message"/>


                                </FormGroup>

                                <Button type="submit" value="Submit"> Submit </Button>
                            </form>
                            </div>
                            <div className="NextPage">   
                            <Link to='/Projects'> {"<"} </Link>  
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
            );
    }
};

export default Contact
```

I have tried to link my backend file with the frontend. I do not understand how to link these files. I have tried using require email.js in my contact.js but it does not work.

I have this error:

```
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js
    Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in '/Users/informatique/crg/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer'
```

My goal it's send email with my contact form.

Comment: I don't really understand what your problem is. How do you get the data from the client to the server? You mentioned forms. Do you use them? Can you share the relevant code that you already have and why it isn't working and how it should be working?

Comment: Nice, now post the code as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48974276/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to save the form and send the user who registered an email stating he/she successfully registered or something regards to user registration.

You need to create an API endpoint in the back-end. Use express or something like express to build an API endpoint so that your front-end can communicate with the back-end. There are a lot of tutorials available online. It'd be something similar to `localhost:3000/user-registration` which would accept parameters like `name, last name, body, and email`. Once you receive the email, you can then shoot an email to the received email ID.

From the front-end, you can use something like `axios` or `fetch` libraries to make API calls to the back-end. Example,

`Axios.post('localhost:3000/user-registration/', { <send captured form data as params' })`

You can try searching for API calls via these libraries.

Or you can use some online services if you don't wanna create your own server.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, I am not sure if it's possible to send the contact details to your email using nodemailer without using any API. If you don't wanna rely on any backend and just build a static site with a contact form, you can use something like https://formspree.io/ which is dead simple to implement.

Comment: (I have edit my post ↑ ) Sorry rash.tay, my post is not very explicit . I want to make a simple contact form for the moment.

Comment: @crg63 I have made an edit to my answer. Without an API endpoint, it'd be difficult to send data via nodemailer. Maybe https://ciunkos.com/creating-contact-forms-with-nodemailer-and-react might help you.

Or you might have to use some third-party services. Try https://formspree.io/

Comment: I go look your links.  Thank you rash !
EDIT: I have already see the tuto of ciunkos. But apparently it missing an step or google Manage APIs has have change. I'll try to know more.